# <input type='range'> only trigger on:change when key up

Tags: typescript, svelte

## Context / Current behaviour

In my svelte project, I have an `<input type='range'>`.

I have a function `handleinput` and a function `handlechange`.

handleinput: smooth graphics update -> should happen smoothly while the bar moves.

handlechange: should happen only when the user decided for a value. (Think: changes to the query in the url bar)

---

It's easy to keep these separate when the user uses mouse or touch:
`<input type='range' on:change={handlechange} on:input={handleinput}>`.

But when the user navigates this element using the keyboard, the following happens:
He presses the → key. Since he wants to move it quite far, he keeps the key pressed.

While the key is pressed, multiple intermediate events happen, each time the bar progresses one step.

For each intermediate event, both `handlechange` and `handleinput` are triggered!
(why???)

---

## Desired behaviour:

Each intermediate event should only trigger `on:change`. On key up, `on:input` should be triggered once.

How can I get this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot prevent the events from happening. The system simply fires key press events based on the user's keyboard repeat rate.

You can however prevent the event from propagating or not do anything when the event happens under specific circumstances.

E.g. the state of the keyboard can be tracked and you can disabled the logic of the change handler while a key is pressed. This can get fairly complicated if you want to cover every case, here is a rough outline:

```html
<script>
    let changeActive = true;
    
    const onChange = e => {
        if (changeActive == false)
            return; // possibly also .stopPropagation()

        // Handle change
    }
    const onInput = e => {
        // Handle input
    }

    const arrows = new Set(['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowDown']);
    const onKeyDown = e => {
        if (arrows.has(e.key))
            changeActive = false;
    };
    const onKeyUp = e => {
        if (arrows.has(e.key)) {
            changeActive = true;

            // Fake change event at the end of keyboard input
            const event = new CustomEvent('change');
            e.target.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    };
</script>

<input type=range min=0 max=100
       on:change={onChange} on:input={onInput}
       on:keydown={onKeyDown} on:keyup={onKeyUp} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f1190c3ed74047e98c54748430efd8ba?version=3.49.0)

(You might want to track each arrow state individually.)